# How to process files in batch with PDF OCR?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-vision

I would like to process 20000 PDFS in batch asynchronously with Google OCR, but I did not find documentation releated with it, I already tried using client.asyncBatchAnnotateFilesAsync fuction;

```
List<AsyncAnnotateFileRequest> requests = new ArrayList<>();
for (MultipartFile file : files) {
    GcsSource gcsSource = GcsSource.newBuilder().setUri(gcsSourcePath + file.getOriginalFilename()).build();
    InputConfig inputConfig = InputConfig.newBuilder().setMimeType("application/pdf").setGcsSource(gcsSource)
            .build();
    GcsDestination gcsDestination = GcsDestination.newBuilder()
            .setUri(gcsDestinationPath + file.getOriginalFilename()).build();
    OutputConfig outputConfig = OutputConfig.newBuilder().setBatchSize(2).setGcsDestination(gcsDestination)
            .build();
    AsyncAnnotateFileRequest request = AsyncAnnotateFileRequest.newBuilder().addFeatures(feature)
            .setInputConfig(inputConfig).setOutputConfig(outputConfig).build();
    requests.add(request);

}
AsyncBatchAnnotateFilesRequest request = AsyncBatchAnnotateFilesRequest.newBuilder().addAllRequests(requests)
        .build();
AsyncBatchAnnotateFilesResponse response = client.asyncBatchAnnotateFilesAsync(request).get();
System.out.println("Waiting for the operation to finish.");
```

But what I get is an error message

```
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: At this time, only single requests are supported for asynchronous processing.
```

If google does not provide batch process why de they provide asyncBatchAnnotateFilesAsync? Maybe am I using an old version? Does asyncBatchAnnotateFilesAsync function work in other beta version?

Comment: The documentation points to a single file (up to 2,000 pages) as source and not multiple files in a single request. https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/pdf#vision_text_detection_pdf_gcs-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple requests on a single call are not supported by the Vision service.

This may be confusing because, according to the [RPC API documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.vision.v1#google.cloud.vision.v1.AsyncBatchAnnotateFilesRequest) you could indeed provide multiple requests on a single service call (1 file per request), still, according to this [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117112737) there is a known limitation on the Vision service and currently it can only take one request at a time.

Comment: Well, but finally what is the answer? Does it work?

Comment: No, it does not work. While the API is prepared to accept multiple request, the service it ultimately calls does not support that yet.

Answer (score 0):

Since they limit to just 1 file per request, can you just send in 20k requests? They are async requests so it should be pretty fast to send those in.